# Grease Pencil Curve Editing button not showing up in the UI

Tags: bezier-curves, grease-pencil

I've tested in versions 2.92, 2.93 and 3.0.

I open a new project, add an empty grease pencil object, paint a stroke, select it and go into edit mode. But it doesn't show the curve editing that was introduced in 2.92

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modes/edit/curve_editing.html

What am I doing wrong?

The documentation says

```
Select the desired strokes to edit as curves.

Activate curve editing in the 3D Viewport’s header with the toggle button (Bézier curve icon).

Once activated you can:

    Edit the curves with the curve handles.

    Select strokes to automatically convert them to curves.
```

But that icon is just not there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[image: right upper corner]
Click on the right upper corner on the small grey button (in edit mode), the header will appear.